# How To Call Javascript-Function on RadioButton-Selection?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

This is how my RadioButtonList looks(ASP.NET):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListGutscheinArt" Visible="true" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem ID="ListItemZugAbonnement" Value="1" Selected="True" />
      <asp:ListItem ID="ListItemBestellungHalbtax" Text="Bestellung Halbtax" Value="2" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I also created a Javascript Function called `backendClick()` which animates elements on my page....

```
function backendClick() {
            $("#PanelPassnummer").fadeIn();
            $("#textbox").animate({ height: '795px' }, "slow");
            $('#Wrapper').animate({ paddingBottom: '20%' }, "slow");
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#weiterButtonAbstand").offset().top }, "slow");
            $('#weiterButtonAbstand').animate({ marginBottom: '8%' }, "slow");
}
```

My Goal is to execute the Function, `backendClick()` when the `ListItemBestellungHalbtax` is selected. ***NOT CLICKED***, the function will be executed when the page is reloading, so the button is already selected when the page loaded.

Now in my C# code behind, i tried like this: (In `protected void Page_Load`)

```
if(RadioButtonListGutscheinArt.SelectedValue == Convert.ToString(2))
  {
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Callfunction", "backendClick()", true);     

  }
```

But with no success....
Any Suggestion on how to do it? Let me know if further information is required.. Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want to execute the function when the page is loading? Then use `AutoPostBack=true`. Every time you select something in your RBList, it will do a postback and your page will reload

Comment: my issue is, that my elements dont animate when i reload the page(and if radiobutton 2 is selected). @Marco

Comment: i would like to know how it works. cause it doesnt work with RegisterStartUpScipt @Marco

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `$(function() {if($("#<%=ListItemBestellungHalbtax.ClientID %>").selected
) {backendClick()}});`

Comment: and how do i implement this in my pageload in c# code behind @Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using asp controls the ID changes in the client side and that's explain why your jquery functions doesn't work.
You should add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your asp controls to remain with the same ID.

So try this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListGutscheinArt" ClientIDMode="Static" Visible="true" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem ID="ListItemZugAbonnement" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="1" Selected="True" />
      <asp:ListItem ID="ListItemBestellungHalbtax" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Bestellung Halbtax" Value="2" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Now JQuery selector will work for you. try this:

```
$('#RadioButtonListGutscheinArt input').change(
    function(event){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && event.target.id=="ListItemBestellungHalbtax") {
            backendClick();
        }
    });
```

And for invoking the function every time the page is reloading you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   backendClick();
   //will check the radio button every time
   $('#ListItemBestellungHalbtax').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it doesnt work, after the page reloads, nothing happens...... maybe i did something wrong in my code behind: `if (ListItemBestellungHalbtax.Selected == true)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Callfunction", "backendClick()", true);

            }`

Comment: This is client side, there is no need to use the code behind for it.

Comment: i fixed it, now it works. But it executes when the page loads for the first time. How do i change it, that it doesnt execute when the page loads for the first time

Comment: how can i create a if in javascript, that checks if my ListItemBestellungHalbtax is checked?

Comment: if ($('#ListItemBestellungHalbtax ').is(":checked"))

Comment: this if doesnt work for me. i dont think the if is wrong. is it possible that my radiobutton selection is not getting saved when i reload the page? cause everytime its selected, but the if doesnt catch it

Comment: [take a look at his please](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39079730/6289340)

Comment: @AlessandroMinneci I answered you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a script block on your aspx page with the following content inside:

```
$(function() {
    if($("#<%=ListItemBestellungHalbtax.ClientID %>").is(':checked')) {
        backendClick();
    }
})
```

If you're using `ClientIDMode="Static"` then you can omit the `#<%=ListItemBestellungHalbtax.ClientID %>` call and just use the regular Id value.